# How can i make this if else statement if the document uploaded it will check icon but if not it will have an x icon

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm making my project and I have something that I don't understand. I want to make an if/else statement or anything that if all the document was uploaded in the database and no one missing it will have a check icon but if there were missing or no upload documents in the database it will have an x icon. The picture or link below is my database. The below code is the data I want to complete.

```
$vsoi = $row['soi'];
$vciv = $row['civ'];
$vpromo = $row['promo'];
$vassign = $row['assign'];
$vawards = $row['awards'];
$venlist = $row['enlist'];
$vlongpay = $row['longpay'];
$vfamily = $row['family'];
$vsaln = $row['saln'];
$vepem = $row['epem'];
```

[image]

This is the result I want to make.

If documents are complete.
[image]

and if not complete.

[image]

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Will that record in the database? Document uploaded or not?

Comment: @HasithaMJayawardana The documents are uploaded.

Comment: How you identify if the document is not uploaded? Do you need help regarding that or how to show icon depending on the document uploaded or not?

Comment: @HasithaMJayawardana In 10 documents if one is missing or non documents was upload it will show an X icon base on the pic above and if the documents is complete it will show a check icon.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried or do you have that HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure is this the solution that you are asking. Because you didn't post more information and the database structure. So I will post the answer as per my assumptions to give you an idea. I see in your database there are `documents/` and also `documents/CPLATEC.docx`. So I assume  `documents/` as `NOT UPLOADED` and `documents/CPLATEC.docx` as `UPLOADED` and also the field type as `VARCHAR`. So based on that here is the answer,

I see a series of documents in the whole table but I will only get this `soi` as for the example.

```
<?php
$vsoi = $row['soi'];
$imageSrc = '';

if ($vsoi == 'documents/') {
   $imageSrc = 'img_for_uploaded.png';
} else {
   $imageSrc = 'img_for_not_uploaded.png';
}
?>
```

You have to place the following inside the table row right to the delete button.

```
<img src="<?php echo $imageSrc ; ?>" />
```

Or just place them inside the table row.

```
if ($vsoi == 'documents/') {
   echo '<img src="img_for_uploaded.png" />'
} else {
   echo '<img src="img_for_not_uploaded.png" />'
}
```

Hope this helps you.